# Try to display the query result to display on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need help again... I am trying to list out the main category list, and besides each category, there is a view button to see its subs and display within the same page. Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" style="margin-top:20px;">
<tr><td align="center"><font size="6">Categories</font></td></tr></table>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("Select * FROM categories WHERE top_cat_id = 0")
?>
<div id="mainCat">
<form method="POST" id="viewSub" action="">
<table width="100%" align="center" class="categories">
<tr><td colspan="3" style="background-color:#000; color:#FFF; font-size:16px;">Main Categories</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" width="10%" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">ID</td>
<td align="center" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Categorie Name</td>
<td align="center" width="30%" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Subcategories</td></tr>
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<tr><input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="'.$data['cat_id'].'"><td align="center">'.$data['cat_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.ucwords(strtolower($data['cat_name'])).'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="View" /></td></tr>';
}
?>
</table></form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#viewSub").bind('submit',function() {
        var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();
        $.post('subcategories.php',{cat_id:cat_id}, function(data){
        $("#subCat").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
);
</script>
<div id="subCat">

</div>
```

As you can see, I guess the jQuery function only listen to the first View button, because no matter with button I click, it only returns me the subs of the first main category. Is there any way to make it work? like using onclick action? I am not good with javascript, so I need help to get this to work...

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need form submit for that. Just replace your submit button with something like `<input class="viewIt" value="VIEW" type="button" />` and then replace your jquery code `$("#viewSub").bind('submit',function(){` with `$(".viewIt").click(function(){`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" style="margin-top:20px;">
<tr><td align="center"><font size="6">Categories</font></td></tr></table>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("Select * FROM categories WHERE top_cat_id = 0");
?>
<div id="mainCat">
<!--<form method="POST" id="viewSub" action="">-->
<table width="100%" align="center" class="categories">
<tr><td colspan="3" style="background-color:#000; color:#FFF; font-size:16px;">Main Categories</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" width="10%" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">ID</td>
<td align="center" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Categorie Name</td>
<td align="center" width="30%" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Subcategories</td></tr>
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<tr><input type="hidden" class="cat_id_'.$data['cat_id'].'" value="'.$data['cat_id'].'"><td align="center">'.$data['cat_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.ucwords(strtolower($data['cat_name'])).'</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="button" class="viewData" name="'.$data['cat_id'].'" value="View" /></td></tr>';
}
?>
</table><!--</form>-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".viewData").click(function(){
        var cat_id = $(".cat_id_"+$(this).attr("name")).val();
       $.post('subcategories.php',{cat_id:cat_id}, function(data){
        $("#subCat").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div id="subCat">

</div>
```

I am assuming your `AJAX` request works fine.

P.S. Use prepared statements for your SQL query further. Because this code is not secure.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but now in my subcategories.php to get the value of the cat_id, I use $catId = $_POST['cat_id'], and I get undefined index $catId error......

Comment: My code works fine, to test it add `data = cat_id` before ` $("#subCat").html(data);` and remove `$.post` request, don't forget to remove ending `})`.

Did your code work before my reply?

Comment: Make sure you use `$_POST['cat_id']` in `subcategories.php`. It should be working. If not then I do not know. Please tell me how is it going now?

Comment: sorry, never mind~ I missed the hidden type part~~ it works~ thanks for you help~~